# Why variable 'pass' change it's value after stack buffer overflow?

Tags: c, stack-overflow, buffer-overflow, stack-smash

I can't understand what's happening with `buf1` and `pass` in `main()`. I understand that after buffer overflow in `gets(buf1)`:

1. Firstly (by input more then 15 characters), we are actually 
   changing calling frame for calling function `main()`
2. Secondly (if keep input more then 19 characters), then we will start change return address of calling function `main()`.

But why after 16 character in `gets` (`buf1`) (`123456789012345**6**`) we get pass equal 54 (which is ASCII code for `6`). We do not overflow `pass` variable so why we get this `pass = 54`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int CommandInjection(char *varCommand)
{
    char cat[] = "cat ";
    char *command;
    size_t commandLength;

    commandLength = strlen(cat) + strlen(varCommand) + 1;
    command = (char *) malloc(commandLength);
    strncpy(command, cat, commandLength);
    strncat(command, varCommand, (commandLength - strlen(cat)) );

    system(command); //The function system is executed with the input entered by the user. The input can be dangerous.

    return (0);
}

int main(void)
{
    char buf1[15];
    char varCommand[30];
    bool pass = 0;

    printf("\nEnter the password: \n(If you enter more than 15 characters you can break the security)\n");
    gets(buf1); //Function that does not make bound checking

    if(strcmp(buf1, "thepassword"))
    {
        printf ("\nWrong Password\n PASS=%d", pass);
        if(pass==true)
            printf ("\nHowever, there was memory corruption and you can enter to other part of the  program\n pass=%d", pass);
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("\nCorrect Password\n");
        pass = true;
    }

    if(pass == true)
    {
        // Don't must enter here if the password is wrong
        printf ("\nEnter the file name (for example: text.txt; ls -l)\n");
        gets(varCommand); //There is no input validation  
        CommandInjection(varCommand);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: don't use `gets()`. use `fgets()` instead

Comment: buf1 is 15 bytes long, if you try to put 16 characters in it you'll get: buf1=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]. The 16th. character is an overflow into the pass parameter, that's why you're getting 16(ASCII 54) there. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: In fact `char buf1[15]`; can only accept a **14-char** password, plus the string terminator. After that you are getting Undefined Behaviour, so anything can happen. Focus on making sure the code works robustly, not on the side-effects of failure. `pass` remained `0` when I entered too many characters.

Comment: @IshayPeled, yes, you have understood me right.

Comment: @Weather, but I want understand this because I want understand how overflow work on stack, from security point of view.